# PHP issue version with PhpMyAdmin 5.0.4

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

Here is my problem:
I have a debian 10 buster.
I had (previously) an older version of Phpmyadmin installed, and it worked fine.

I tried to upgrade to phpmyadmin 5.0.4.
I also upgraded php, to run php 7.4.12 (php -v)

When I browse to the phpmyadmin page, I see:

> PHP 7.1.3+ is required. Currently installed version is:
> 7.0.33-37+0~20201103.43+debian9~1.gbp25a3d7

It looks to me that the phpmyadmin page does not use the correct PHP version, but I can't find what to do to correct that :-(

I just can't find (through google) a way to modify this.
Could you please help or guide me somehow ?

Sorry for my poor English and.. keep up the good work !

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the old version of PHP, and enable the new version in Apache.

Disable like so: (adjust the version number according to the version you want to disable.)

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
```

Enable like so:(adjust the version number according to the version you want to enable.)

```
sudo a2enmod php7.4
```

After issueing the disable / enable commands --  You need to restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To be sure what version of php you are currently "running" you can issue the following on the command line:

```
php --version
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you so much for this solution Zak.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer :) and vote up if you deem worthy

Answer (score 1):

I had faced same problem, it is related to the phpmyadmin version you had installed you must ensure it is compitaple with php version.
For php5.6 it is better to use phpmyadmin 4.9.11 version, you can find it in the url below:
https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/

After that just upload phpmyadmin version to your ssh server and unzip it in the path

> /usr/share/

, then to get phpmyadmin running on the browser make sure the unzipped folder name is

> 'phpmyadmin/'

I installed phpmyadmin version compitable with php7 then replacedd all the files/folders inside /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ with the files/folders that are in the unziped file phpmyadmin4.9.11 and get phpmyadmin running on my browser.

Hope this help you...